# AWS CDK no perms for cloudformation:ListStackResources after upgrade to v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

After I upgraded to CDK v2 and re-bootstrapped I'm getting this message when I diff/deploy:

> User: arn:aws:sts::12.....09:assumed-role/cdk-h.....ds-deploy-role-12......09-us-east-2/aws-cdk-c.....e is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:ListStackResources on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:12.....09:stack/..../d0....be because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:ListStackResources action.

The role referenced in the email was generated when I rebootstrapped for v2. Upon examination it indeed does not contain the cloudformation:ListStackResources action.

How should I proceed?

I could

```
a)  Manually modify the role to include that action
b)  Re-run some cdk command to fix the role?
c)  Re-code something in my stack because of some v1-v2 incompatibility?
d)  ?????
```

I'm using the C# library. I'm trying not to regret performing the upgrade. ;P

Comment: had the same issue, had to update the role manually.

Comment: There's a github issue [diff: >=2.11.0 not authorized to perform: cloudformation:ListStackResources](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19351) that may apply.  Includes a fix.

Comment: @fedonev that bug is still open. There is a hack-y workaround for manually changing some dev dependency versions. I couldn’t figure out how that fit into a C# project.